# private network ether is 0 after block synchronization

Tags: synchronization, accounts

i'm taking a course.

in this course we create a private network and create some ether(miner.start(1))

i check my account and i have some ether.

eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0]) => 12

i practice some transactions between accounts. 
we also practice making a simple contract and deploying it.

everything is fine.

a couple of days later i open **geth console** i check the balance and everything intact.

a couple of minutes later, without me doing anything, i see:

```
INFO [09-07|00:03:18] Block synchronisation started 
WARN [09-07|00:03:23] Chain split detected                     number=1343 hash=83c5c1…1d6816 drop=161 dropfrom=dd2711…3610a4 add=129 addfrom=cae0a0…2f1d63
INFO [09-07|00:03:24] Imported new chain segment               blocks=177 txs=1 mgas=0.125 elapsed=3.276s mgasps=0.038 number=1520 hash=a361ad…f9eb65
INFO [09-07|00:03:28] Imported new chain segment               blocks=768 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=4.388s mgasps=0.000 number=2288 hash=b604e9…3f3143
INFO [09-07|00:03:36] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1435 txs=17 mgas=0.887 elapsed=8.004s mgasps=0.111 number=3723 hash=fa8f1d…b0f9c7
INFO [09-07|00:03:39] Imported new chain segment               blocks=485  txs=11 mgas=0.234 elapsed=2.632s mgasps=0.089 number=4208 hash=e61a89…7b02df
INFO [09-07|00:03:45] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1112 txs=13 mgas=0.731 elapsed=6.064s mgasps=0.120 number=5320 hash=14afe6…ffbab4
INFO [09-07|00:15:13] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1    txs=0  mgas=0.000 elapsed=7.481ms mgasps=0.000 number=5321 hash=d933c2…0b1f03
INFO [09-07|00:15:13] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1    txs=0  mgas=0.000 elapsed=10.734ms mgasps=0.000 number=5322 hash=2d4437…84ab97
```

check the account balance and it's 0.

maybe i haven't waited till the synchronization has actually finished?

can someone explain to me what is going on? and how can i fix it so i won't have to start over with the private network?

Comment: Your node is connected to another node with the same genesis file. You can have your own network if you genesis is differente, for example a different network id. Or you can disable connectivity with `--nodiscover --nat none --maxpeers 0`.

Answer (score 1):

**`geth console`** would synchronize ethereum main net, so current situation isn't private network. You can execute the command below:

```
geth --datadir=~/Downloads/dev console
```

`~/Downloads/dev` directory is datadir of saving all data.

Hope it helps~

Comment: when i start geth i use

./bin/geth --datadir=./datadir console   
command

Comment: Yes, you are right~